# How to remove duplicate line in a file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, io, filewriter

Hi I'm using the below method to write to a file from the Jtextarea and I call this method every 30 second within a Timer but instead to add only new line in file it rewrite the entire lines contained in Jtextarea so then I have duplicate lines. I want to avoid this and update the file just with new lines. Could you help me please.

```
public void loger() {

    FileWriter writer = null;

    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+date()+".txt" , true);
        textArea.write(writer);

        } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("log error");
        exception.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println("Error closing writer");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you are creating a new file every 30 seconds and would like for each file to contain only messages for the past 30 seconds?

Comment: No I'm just updating the same file every 30 seconds.

Comment: `writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+Date()+".txt" , true);`  If `Date()` is a method it should be called `date()`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew I changed it yes it's a method.

Comment: The name "MBM_Log_"+date()+".txt" allow to me to get every day a log file e.g MBM_Log_20-03-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code instead to write to the file from the Jtextarea I write the string (LOG) directly to the file. My method loger() become as below : 
public void loger (String texLine){

```
    FileWriter writer = null;

    try {       
        writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+date()+".txt" , true);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
        out.printf("%s"+"%n", texLine);
                    out.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("log error");
        exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println("Error closing writer");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

And then then I write the log to the Jtextarea to be displayed in GUI and calling the method loger() to write to the file e.g:

textArea.append(dateTime()+ " : Alarm sound muted by the Operator from the Menu Bar ");

loger(dateTime()+ " : Alarm sound muted by the Operator from the Menu Bar ");

By this way I have the logs in Jtextarea and in the file. My problem is resolved when I restart the application the file is not erased and the new log is added to the file.
Thanks to all.

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted, so that the question won't show up in the Unanswered ones any longer. And you can upvote my answer for reputation, if you feel that I at least gave you the idea.

Comment: I'm new in this site so can't vote and I have to wait 16H to accept to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+Date()+".txt" , true);
```

The code above uses appending boolean flag in the constructor, make it false and retry:

```
writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+Date()+".txt" , false);
```

To avoid creating a new file each time, initialize your file writer once outside the method and then use it:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+date()+".txt" , true);

public void loger() {

    try {       
        textArea.write(writer);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("log error");
        exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println("Error closing writer");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want to avoid loosing the content of my file when I restart the application. With false it create a new one erasing the content of the file.

Comment: Thanks but I get this error now : Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: @Abs so create this filewriter within a try-catch block separately. you are a newbie in java i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+Date()+".txt" , true);
```

to:

```
writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+Date()+".txt", false);
```

or just:

```
writer = new FileWriter("MBM_Log_"+Date()+".txt");
```

[The constructor you're using for `FileWriter` takes two arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29): a `String` filename and `boolean` which says whether to append to the file if it already exists.  As you currently have this set to `true` it is appending the contexts of the text area on to the file instead of replacing the file with one with just the current text.

If you want to keep the existing contents of the file either:

- Keep using the append option and only update the file when you close the application.
- Read the contents of the file on application start up and write this out to the new file before adding the current contents of the text area.

Comment: I already tested this but when I restart my application the file is erased by a new one and then I lose my logs. There is another way ?

Comment: @Dave-1. We need to read the log from the file and the application should run for a long time it monitor the traffic from the router.2. how to this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to append to the file (so leave `true` in the constructor).

What you are doing somewhat wrong is to use a Swing component to store data. Swing components are designed to display data. Imagine what would happen if your manager / supervisor / teacher told you to use another GUI library or convert the whole application to a web server - you would have to abandon JTextArea and would then have nowhere to save log messages.

You should have some collection of log messages, for example a `List` and then display the messages using this collection. Your log message class can have some function to convert the log message into a `String`. Then it would be just a question to go through the list every 30 seconds and append the messages whose timestamp is newer than the time of the last save.

Comment: I write my logs directly to the file to keep history + append to Jtextarea for display. I tested it yesterday in working fine. Anyway thanks for your answer.